# Expectation of discounted Indicator function under Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Assume stock price follows geometric Brownian motion: $$ \frac{dS_t}{S_t}=rdt+bdW_t$$ where $r,b$ are constants and $W_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. Define 
$$V_t=\sup_{\tau \in [t,T]}\{\, E[e^{-r(\tau-t)}(K-S_\tau)^{+}]|F_t\}\,$$ and
$$\tau*=\inf\{\,u\in[t,T]| V_u=(K-S_u)^{+}\}\,$$ where $K, T$ are constants, $(F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a filtration and $(K-S_u)^{+}=\max(K-S_u,0)$.

I want to find following expectation.

$$E[e^{-r(u-t)}\mathbb{1}_{\{\,K>S_u,\tau^*>u\}\,}|F_t]$$
Here $u\in [t,T]$ and $\mathbb{1}_{\{\,K>S_u,\tau^*>u\}\,}$ is the indicator function.

Any comments, reference or suggestions appreciated. The only reference I found was Shreve(Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models) section 3.7.3 which mention about joint density function. But I am not sure how to get a joint density function when you have $\tau*$ is defined as above.

Comment: Differentiate $V_t$ with respect to $K$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank You!. So I differentiate the expression. This let me to simplify $E[e^{-r(u-t)}1_{ \{\, K>S_u,\tau^*>u \}\, }]$ to $E[\frac{dV_u}{dK}1_{\{\,\tau^*>u\}\,}|F_t]$. Now if I know what is the density function, then I can integrate from 0 to $\tau^*$. Any hint about the density function I should use in this case?